# 301 redirection of all pages except the homepage

Tags: .htaccess

What I'm trying to achieve is a 301 redirection of all the pages/resources for a domain *except* the root of the site every page then should move from www.example.com/example.com to old.example.com.

I'm not an htaccess guru but this is the solution I came up with...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond !^$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://old.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But seems not to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were missing the TestString in the RewriteCond

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
#if not root
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?$ [NC]
#redirect
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://old.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```