# Redirect to another domain except for home page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect my old website to a new domain with a few exceptions. These are the current rules that are in my .htaccess file and they are working great:

```
RewriteEngine on

# handle both specific URL redirects
RewriteRule ^/?product-(?:tag|categories)/([\w-]+) https://www.newdomain.com/parts?category=$1 [R=301,L,NC,QSA]

# redirect everything else
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.newdoamin.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Now I want to add another rule. I want every page to be redirected to the new domain beside the home page on the old site. With that being said, I still want these exsiting rules to work if it is not the home page.

How can I add another redirect rule to my current htaccess that will not redirect when someone access the home page on the old domain and still apply my current rules?

I was trying to use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994501/301-redirection-of-all-pages-except-the-homepage) but I couldn't get my existing rules to work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine on

# handle both specific URL redirects
RewriteRule ^/?product-(?:tag|categories)/([\w-]+) https://www.newdomain.com/parts?category=$1 [R=301,L,NC,QSA]

# redirect everything else
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)$ https://www.newdoamin.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

`.+` matches every URI except the home page. Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: Thanks again! And thank you for the clarification on .+